The fields ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}]$ and ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}}]$ are different?
We can easily  confirm that the fields ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}]$ and ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}}]$ are different using CAS.
I would like to show that claim by hand.
Let us define $\alpha_1 = \sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}$ and $\alpha_2 = \sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}}$.
-- One way is to show that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ has a degree greater than 6. A lengthy computation shows that this algebraic number is a root of $x^9 - 18x^6 - 81x^3 - 216$. Is there an elementary way to show that this polynomial is irreducible?
-- Another way would be to find an element in ${\mathbb Q}(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ which is a root of a simpler polynomial of degree greater than 6, and for which irreducibility is easy to check. Is there such an element?
-- Is there a way to show that the two fields are different without any computation, presumably with a bit of Galois theory? CAS tells us that the Galois group of the normal closure of ${\mathbb Q}[\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}]$ is $S_3 \times S_3$ and I can show this by hand too, but this involves lengthy computations.

For the second question, you won’t find anything of degree greater than 6 and less than 9 because it must have degree a multiple of 3

@lhf Yes, we are looking for a degree 9 polynomial, not too hard to compute and whose irreducibility is easy to show.

How do you show that the Galois group of the normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ is $S_3 \times S_3$?

@psl2Z It is a bit long to type in a comment.
One must find two Galois subfields $K_1$ and $K_2$ such that $K_1K_2$ is the normal closure and $K_1 \cap K_2 = {\bf Q}$. Explicit computations give $K_1 = {\bf Q}[i\sqrt{3}, \alpha_1\alpha_2]$, $K_2 = {\bf Q}[i\sqrt{6}, \alpha_1\alpha_2(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)]$. Showing that $K_1 \cap K_2 = {\bf Q}$ is equivalent to showing that ${\bf Q}[\alpha_1] \neq {\bf Q}[\alpha_2]$ but is easier because $K_1 \cap K_2$ is Galois.

Then $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]7)$ which must be wrong. Their minimal polynomials are different.

@BobDobbs Two algebraic numbers may generate the same field without having the same minimal polynomial.

@coudy  Interesting. How much their minimal polynomials are different?

For example, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$ have different minimal polynomials but generate the same field over $\bf Q$.

@coudy İn the simple example you give, discriminants of the minimal polynomials are equal.

@BobDobbs Indeed, so you suggest computing the discriminant of the number fields. They are indeed different, as shown by some computer algebra software. That works but I am not sure how easy it is to carry the computation by hand.

Let us set $a=\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}},b=\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}},F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for ease of typing. Let us observe that each of the numbers $a, b$ is of degree $3$ over $F$. We will prove that $b\notin F(a) $.
Let us assume on the contrary that $b\in F(a) $. Then we have $$b=pa^2+qa+r$$ for some $p, q, r\in F$. Next let us note that all numbers involved are real and the field $F(a) \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ and further the numbers $a, a^2,b$ are pure radicals over $F$ so that their traces are $0$. Applying trace on the above equation then gives us $$0=p\cdot 0+q\cdot 0+3r$$ (as $[F(a) :F] =3$). This gives us $r=0$ so that we have $$ab=pa^3+qa^2$$ and let us note that $a^3\in F$ and $ab=\sqrt[3]{7}$ is also a pure radical over $F$. Applying traces again we get $$0=3pa^3+q\cdot 0$$ ie $p=0$. Hence we have $b=qa$ for some $q\in F$. This means that $a^2b=qa^3\in F$. One can check that $$a^2b=\sqrt[3]{7(3+\sqrt{2})}$$ is not a member of $F$ and this gives us a contradiction.
Hence $b\notin F(a) $ and fields $F(a), F(b) $ are different.

If you like algebraic number theory, consider the extensions as extensions of $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha=\sqrt 2$. Then $K_1=K(\beta),K_2=K(\gamma)$ with $\beta^3-(3+\alpha)= 0$ and $\gamma^3-(3-\alpha)=0$. Now $3+\alpha,3-\alpha$ are two non-associated primes in $K$ (the ones lying above $7$) and $3+\alpha$ ramifies in $K_1$, but does not ramify in $K_2$ (as $t^3-(3-\alpha)\equiv t^3-6\mod(3+\alpha)$ is separable mod $3+\alpha$), so the extensions are not the same.
The idea to consider the extensions over $K$ rather than $\Bbb Q$ comes from the observation that the extensions are isomorphic over $\Bbb Q$ (the minimal polynomials of $\beta,\gamma$ over $\Bbb Q$ are the same), but this isomorphism carries $\sqrt2$ to $-\sqrt2$, so this suggests to look at this over $K$ in order to distinguish them.

Let $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{-3})$.
If $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}) = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}})$, then $K(\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{2}}) = K(\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{2}})$. Since $K$ contains cube roots of unity, when $a$ and $b$ are in $K$ we have $K(\sqrt[3]{a}) = K(\sqrt[3]{b}) \Rightarrow a = bc^3$ or $a = b^2c^3$ for some $c \in K^\times$: see Theorem 5.7 here with $n=3$.
Taking $a = 3+\sqrt{2}$ and $b = 3-\sqrt{2}$, which are in $K$, having $a/b$ or $a/b^2$ be a cube in $K$ implies $ab^2$ or $ab$ is a cube in $K$. To prove $ab^2 = 7(3-\sqrt{2})$ and $ab = 7$ are not cubes in $K$, we place $K$ into a larger field where it's more obvious that $7$ and $7(3-\sqrt{2})$ are not cubes.  In the $7$-adic numbers $\mathbf Q_7$, $2$ and $-3$ are squares by Hensel's lemma since $2 \equiv 3^2 \bmod 7$ and $-3 \equiv 2^2 \bmod 7$. Thus there is an embedding $K \to \mathbf Q_7$ by mapping $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ to either square root of $2$ and either square root of $-3$ in $\mathbf Q_7$. Map $\sqrt{2}$ in $K$ to the $7$-adic square root of $2$ that is $4 \bmod 7$. Then $3-\sqrt{2}$ is mapped to $3 - 4 \equiv -1 \bmod 7$, so $7(3-\sqrt{2})$ in $K$ is mapped to $7$ times a $7$-adic unit. Thus $7$ and $7(3-\sqrt{2})$ in $K$ are both uniformizers in $\mathbf Q_7$ and hence are not cubes in $\mathbf Q_7$, so they also are not cubes in $K$.
