Subfields of order 3 of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]{7}]$
I would like to show that ${\bf Q}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is the unique subfield of order 3 of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{7}]$.
I found a way by computing the degree of the Galois extension ${\bf Q}[\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{7}]$ and used the Sylow theorem to count the 4-Sylow groups. This showed that the only degree 3 subfields of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{7}]$ are ${\bf Q}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ and its two conjugates. This seems too complicated though. Is there an easier proof? Without using complex numbers?

Interesting question. I guess, this also answers one of your previous questions.

@BobDobbs I am not sure at that point. If you think it does, I would be happy if you answer the other question, which is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4975727/the-fields-mathbb-q-sqrt33-sqrt2-and-mathbb-q-sqrt33-sqrt

Suppose $K \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}, \sqrt{2})$ is a subfield with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 3$. Then $X^3-7$ has a zero in $K$: the minimal polynomial $P\in K[X]$ of $\sqrt[3]{7}$ over $K$ has degree $1$ or $2$ and divides $X^3-7$ in $K[X]$, therefore it has a linear factor $X-\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in K$ (since $\deg X^3 -7 = 3$). But $X^3-7$ has only one real zero, namely $\sqrt[3]{7}$. Since $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ it follows $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{7}$. Thus $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$.
